# RegEx Matching on text and new line

Tags: regex, sed

I have a file which appends a binary file to a bash script (in this case an ISO). It ultimately gets pulled apart, executing the bash script to install the ISO. The bash script ends in a unique string; "**DATA**" and during its execution the script deletes everything above and including that line.

It doesn't however remove the terminating new line which means the new file (which should just be the binary ISO data) begins with a newline, breaking the ISO.

The regex deleting the data is as follows

```
sed -re '1,/^__DATA__$/d'
```

Viewing the file with `cat -e` I'm trying to match and delete the `$` after `__DATA__$`

```
#cat -et file.bin

echo "I: Installation finished!"$
exit 0$
$
__DATA__$
$
3<ED>M-^PM-^PM-^PM-^PM-^
```

Comment: Try `sed '/^__DATA__$/,+1d' file`

Comment: Or, `sed '/^__DATA__$/{N;/\n$/d}' file`

Comment: Unfortunately not. I tried adding the 1,/ to the start of the regex also with out success

Comment: But why do you need that `1,/`? Do you remove a range then? From the first line till the `__DATA__` line + blank line after?

Comment: I read your question and comments a few times, and I still don't understand what you are trying to do. You explained the context, and your code attempt, but not what it is that you wish to do. From your attempt it seems pretty clear that you want to delete something. What, *exactly*?

Comment: wrt `Most text editors seem to append a new line to the end of the script.` - I'd hope so because otherwise, by definition, the content isn't a text file. Per POSIX every text file (and every line within a text file) ends with `\n` and that is the only type of file that standard UNIX text processing tools and editors are required to work on. Anything else is undefined behavior. Please [edit] your question to include the expected output given your posted sample input.

Comment: Thanks all for the comments-  recognise that the question was poorly worded and I've updated it

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that's exactly what I'm trying to do, delete the first line to the `__DATA__` and the new line after that

Comment: Try `sed -n '/__DATA__/{n;:1;n;p;b1}' file`

Comment: Hi, did it finally help?

Comment: Perfect - it worked with `-re` but not `-n` thanks so much @WiktorStribiżew!!

Comment: Please check the below answer, I explained how it works. Not sure how you made it work with `-re`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using

```
sed -n '/__DATA__/{n;:1;n;p;b1}' file
```

Here, `-n` suppresses the default output of lines, then the first line containing `__DATA__` is found, and then a line is read into the pattern space, and then all subsequent lines are read and printed. So, we skip the part of the file before `__DATA__` line and the next line.

See the [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/jA3Zp8)

```
s='#cat -et file.bin

echo "I: Installation finished!"
exit 0

__DATA__

3<ED>M-^PM-^PM-^PM-^PM-^'

sed -n '/__DATA__/{n;:1;n;p;b1}' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
3<ED>M-^PM-^PM-^PM-^PM-^
```

Comment: Thanks for this Wiktor. This appears to work fine in Ubuntu however not in BusyBox. Perhaps slightly off topic but wondered if you had any idea? ```sed: unterminated {
BusyBox:/ # sed -v
sed: invalid option -- v
BusyBox v1.25.1 (2020-04-29 14:15:19 AEST) multi-call binary.```

Comment: @AlexTurner It is probably due to the `;` inside curly brackets. Try `sed -n -e '/__DATA__/{' -e n -e:1 -e n -e p -e b1 -e '}' file`